# Updating XMLfile Using MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile UpdateElement

Tags: xml, xpath, msbuild

I have an MSBUILD project file and I am trying to checkout some xml files and update a Version element and can't seem to get this to work for the life of me. This seems like it should be a simple solution but I cannot get it to work. I have a simple xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DataSet>
  <Profile>
    <Product>ProductA</Product>
    <Version>1.2.3.4</Version>
  </Profile>
  ~
</DataSet>
```

I can get the Version by using xmlPeek:

```
<XmlPeek XmlInputPath="c:\myProfile.xml"
  Query="DataSet/Profile/Version[../Product = &quot;ProductA&quot;]/text()">
  <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="ProductVersion" />
</XmlPeek>
```

I had  no luck using XmlPoke updating the Version so I tried XmlFile's UpdateElement from XmlFile's class page:

http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.5.0/html/4009fe8c-73c1-154f-ee8c-e9fda7f5fd96.htm

```
  <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile
    TaskAction="UpdateElement"
    File="c:\machine.config"
    XPath="/configuration/configSections/section[@name='system.data']"
    InnerText="NewValue"/>
```

I tried the follwing plus many other XPath versions to which none has worked.

```
  <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile
    TaskAction="UpdateElement"
    File="c:\myProfile.xml"
    XPath="/DataSet/Profile/Version[@Product='ProductA']"
    InnerText="5.6.7.8"
  />
```

What am I missing?
Or does anyone know the correct XPath for xmlpoke

Thanks

Comment: Determining the correct XPath requires information about the corresponding XML. Could you please post relevant portion of the XML that include the target element?

Comment: I thought I did post the relevant xml portion, so I'm assuming you meant the 'xml version' line - I added to original post.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. The XML was already there on top of the post, how can I missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath, `@` is used to reference attribute like `@attribute_name`. So part of your attempted XPath `Version[@Product='ProductA']`, will look for `Version` element that have `Product` attribute value equals 'ProductA', something like the following (which doesn't exist in your XML) :

```
<Version Product="ProductA"/>
```

The correct XPath to get `Version` element by `Product` name would be as follow :

```
/DataSet/Profile[Product='ProductA']/Version
```

This particular part `Profile[Product='ProductA']`, filters `Profile` element that have child element `Product` equals 'ProductA'.

Comment: Thank you so much...much appreciated.